# iptables centOS port forwarding not working

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

I want to forward udp packets coming to port 10500 to 10600, but its not working with the following config.

My iptables looks like this,

```
[root@mymachine ~]# service iptables status
Table: filter
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2    LOG        all  --  224.0.0.0/4          0.0.0.0/0           LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `IP DROP MULTICAST D: '
3    LOG        all  --  240.0.0.0/5          0.0.0.0/0           LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `IP DROP SPOOF E: '
4    LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.0/8         LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `IP DROP LOOPBAK: '

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2    ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:10600 state NEW

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 0
3    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 3
4    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 11
5    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8
6    ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251         udp dpt:5353
7    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
8    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22
9    ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW udp dpt:53
10   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:53
11   ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:69
12   ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:514
13   DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
14   ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:10500
15   ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:10600

Table: nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DNAT       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.80.128      udp dpt:10500 to:192.168.80.128:10600

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

also since it is CentOS , I've added the following.
`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

Tell me where I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you're aiming for, you must add a rule for INPUT filter-table. And add REDIRECTION in nat-table

Example:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 10600 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 10500 REDIRECT --to-port 10600
```

How it works:

First table is *NAT  PREROUTING*. The traffic to tcp:10500 will be **REDIRECT**ed to tcp:10600. After that this traffic will go to table filter *INPUT*, and firewall **ACCEPT**s it.

Answer (score 0):

Try use REDIRECT.
Example: iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -s 0.0.0.0/0 -d 192.168.75.128 -p udp -m udp --dport 10500 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 10600

Answer (score 0):

In `Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT`
line `13   DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0` is rejecting everythihg not allowed before it. Place all your ALLOWED rules before "DROP of everything" or they will be ignored. (Line 14 - 15 must be before line 13 in Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT)